# How is hoisting applied to this JavaScript code?

Tags: javascript

I know this code prints 2 because of varibale hoisting but I do not fully understand how.

I'm going to list everything that I understand and would be very grateful if you could answer with true or false next to each one. You can then add any additional information.

1) The line let b = innerMagic() references the innerMagic() function, which returns a;

2) We have now assigned the value 3 to the variable a, which means return b, should return 3. However at the moment the variable is set to 2, so it returns 2. You can not call a variable before  a variable before it has been assigned.

```js
function magic() {
  let a = 1;
  a = 2;
  let b = innerMagic();
  a = 3;

  return b;

  function innerMagic() {
    return a;
  }
}

console.log(magic())
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with hoisting but just that JS does not pass variables by reference. `b` doesn't "reference" `a`, it just gets assigned the value `2` that the `innerMagic()` call returns.

Answer (score 1):

innerMagic takes the value of a from the outside scope at the time when it's called. So when innerMagic is called, a has the value 2. It returns this value (2), to b, and you return b (2), and that's what you print

Answer (score 1):

"let b = innerMagic() references the innerMagic() function, which returns a;" that's not quite right, it returns the value of a i.e. 2.

At this point both `a` and `b` hold the value 2. `a` is then updated to the value 3 but `b` still has the value 2.

For an explanation of value vs reference take a look at this article on [Explaining Value vs. Reference in Javascript](https://codeburst.io/explaining-value-vs-reference-in-javascript-647a975e12a0)